# How to read input from repl till the end-of-file character in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am implementing a compiler for a contest in clojure. Where the input program should be read from STDIN till the end-of-file character. How can I do that?

Comment: and what have you tried already?

Answer (score 2):

Try [`line-seq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/line-seq) function

```
(line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))
```